# PHP Function Not Running Correctly

Tags: php

```
<?php

function pass($level=2,$length=6) {

    $chars[1] = "023456789abcdefghijmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $chars[2] = "23456789abcdefghijmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    $i = 0;
    $str = "";

    while ($i<=$length) {
        $str .= $chars[$level][mt_rand(0,strlen($chars[$level]))];
        $i++;
    }

    return $str;

}

echo pass(2, 7);

?>
```

When I call the function, I really can't set anything up. pass(2,7) is the same length as pass(1, 9). It's all level 2 and some length. What's wrong?

Comment: Where are you declaring that `$chars` is an array?

Comment: http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/04/15-top-php-coding-tutorials-tips-and.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers seem to ignore the fact that [strings are treated as arrays of characters in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (see the section *String access and modification by character*).

Your script worked fine for me with two modifications:

## First:

You are referencing a character randomly from 0 to the length of the string.  This doesn't work, string arrays are 0-indexed, and therefore 1 less than the length.

Try:

`$str .= $chars[$level][mt_rand(0,strlen($chars[$level]) - 1)];`

## Second:

You are looping through this procedure from 0 to the length specified, meaning that it will loop `$length + 1` times.

Try:

`while ($i < $length) {`

this worked perfectly for me.

Here's sample output:

```
print pass(2, 7) //prints IR5YgGD
print pass(1, 10) //prints d2eyq547gy
```

Comment: Basically what I tried to do, but you've actually explained why it is the way it is. Kudos ^_^

Answer (score 1):

- You need -1 to not overflow.
- You can use substr to [] to access.

  ```
  function pass($level=1,$length=6) {

  $chars = array();
  $chars[0] = "023456789abcdefghijmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  $chars[1] = "23456789abcdefghijmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  $i = 0;
  $str = "";
  while ($i<$length) 
  {
      $index = mt_rand(0,strlen($chars[$level])-1);//It's inclusive you need -1
      $str .= substr($chars[$level],$index,1);//Take the index with 1 for a single char
      //You can also use:
      //$str .= $chars[$level][$index];
      $i++;
  }

  return $str;

  }

  echo pass(0, 7);//Start at 0 because array start at 0. So it's your Level1
  echo pass(1, 7);//Start with 1, it's your Level2    
  ?>
  ```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If you pass 7 as the length, you can get a result of either 7 or 8 characters

Comment: I do not have a compiler of PHP with me now, I am sure you can from what I have wrote found the little glitch. The main point is to use SUBSTR instead of trying to get char with array.

Comment: You can also use {n} to extract the nth character from a string. I think that's what he was trying to do when using []

Comment: It works. Do not forget to pass 1 and 6 now because array start at 0 not 1.

Comment: I tested at : http://writecodeonline.com/php/ pass(0,6) pass(1,6) pass(1,7) and all works. Have a nice day.

Comment: Calling [x] on a string returns the given index. Technically the code is sound. The only problems are that he is using strlen($chars[$level]) in the mt_rand, when he should use (strlen($chars[$level]) - 1), and $i <= $length should just be $i < $length.

Comment: You are right about the -1, this has been in my code above. For the [] I think it's just more clear the way I did it, but well, he can use the way he wants :) What I posted work and should do the job.

Comment: You can change the SUBSTR line in the code above by : $str .= $chars[$level][$index];//Take the index with 1 for a single char and it will works too...

Comment: This answer is fundamentally wrong as far as assumptions about string manipulation go, see the first line of mine.

Comment: @Daok Dunno what to tell you. Doesn't work for me. At least not when I tested it. You may have edited it since. =P

Comment: Yeah I have edited it because it was confusing people. You can use [] but why messing around with all those bracket. I have modify the code this way you can see both solution in the same code.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine

```
<?php

function pass($level=2,$length=6) {

$chars[1] = array("0","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");
$chars[2] = array("2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N,"P","Q","R",""S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");

$i = 0;
$str = "";
while ($i<=$length) {
    $str .= $chars[$level][mt_rand(0,count($chars[$level])-1)];
    $i++;
    }

return $str;

}

echo pass(2, 7);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got. I define the length `mt_rand()` needs, and then use curly braces `{}` to extract the character at the random index:

```
function pass($level=2, $length=6) {

    $chars[1] = "023456789abcdefghijmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $chars[2] = "23456789abcdefghijmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    $i = 0;
    $str = "";
    $charLen = strlen($chars[$level]) -1;

    while ($i<$length) {
        $str .= $chars[$level]{mt_rand(0,$charLen)};
        $i++;
    }

    return $str;
}

$result = pass(2, 21);
```